# How to calculate $\int{\exp \left[ -a\left( x-y \right) ^2-b\left( y-z \right) ^2 \right] dy}$

Tags: integration

I am trying to prove a formula in the textbook. From the textbook it told me that:
$$
\int{\exp \left[ -a\left( x-y \right) ^2-b\left( y-z \right) ^2 \right] dy}=\left( \frac{\pi}{a+b} \right) ^{\frac{3}{2}}\exp \left[ -\frac{ab}{a+b}\left( x-z \right) ^2 \right] 
$$
but I am unable to derive it.
Using Mathematica, I got different result:
[Mathematica result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VmU9.png)

I have no idea how to derive the formula in the textbook.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aren't you missing bounds for the domain of integration? Otherwise you need an additive constant on the right-hand side and dependence on $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the integration is on the real line, we have
\begin{align*}
& \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left[ { - a(x - y)^2  - b(y - z)^2 } \right]dy} 
\\ &
 = \exp \left( { - \frac{{ab}}{{a + b}}(x - z)^2 } \right)\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left[ { - (a + b)\left( {y - \frac{{ax + bz}}{{a + b}}} \right)^2 } \right]dy} 
\\ &
 = \exp \left( { - \frac{{ab}}{{a + b}}(x - z)^2 } \right)\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left[ { - (a + b)t^2 } \right]dt} 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + b} }}\exp \left( { - \frac{{ab}}{{a + b}}(x - z)^2 } \right)\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {e^{ - s^2 } ds} 
\\ &
 = \left( {\frac{\pi }{{a + b}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp \left( { - \frac{{ab}}{{a + b}}(x - z)^2 } \right).
\end{align*}
First we made a change of variables from $y$ to $t$ via $t=y - \frac{{ax + bz}}{{a + b}}$, then we made a further change of variables from $t$ to $s$ via $t = \frac{s}{{\sqrt {a + b} }}$. Note that the power is $1/2$ and not $3/2$.